# Owl slider, ajax load page jump issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel, with ajax, successfully.
An issue i have, is after adding slider items using 'addItem'...the page jumps to the top of the slider.

EG, you may be down near the bottom of the page, and the slider at the top. When the slider has added items, the page jumps back up to the slider.

Anyone else noticed this issue? And how to stop it?

Inside my success callback function:

```
 for(var c=0;c<response.data.length;c++){
     jQuery("myslider").data("owlCarousel").addItem(response.data[c]);
 }

 //jump happens after the above.

 jQuery("myslider").trigger("owl.jumpTo", currentItem)
```

thanks
Shaun

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your situation is exactly identical to mine, but I am also experiencing page jumps when `addItem()` to the carousel. I stepped through the code and found that during `addItem()` the carousel is "destroyed" then rebuilt. Namely the page will have the carousel removed first, causing vertical scroll bar to lengthen and "shift upwards", then the carousel is rebuilt while the vertical scroll bar is still in its original position. The result is as if the page have scrolled up automatically.

A temporary solution is to set `min-height` for the carousel or a `div` wrapping the carousel, as shown in this fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/490/). In fact I believe any method of maintaining the document length before calling `addItem()` may do the trick.